# How Do I Fix This Function?

Tags: functional-programming

I need help with my CS homework, and I don't quite know what to do..

The problem is to define a function and return a string as shown as:

```
1111
    2222
        3333
```

I wrote my function as:

```
def steps():
    for i in range (1,4):
        string = str(i) * 4
        print(string)
```

How do I put in the little spacings? I know  I have to use the '\t', but I do not know where to put it in the function...

Comment: it should be `string = '\t\ * i + str(i) * 4`

Comment: I'm afraid that questions about programming or writing code are off-topic here; see our [help/on-topic].

Comment: @ Euge thank you so much! But somehow, the output returns None at the end.. how do I get rid of that?